# Whats the proper way to write subnet size with / notation?

Tags: subnet

If I need to write a Subnet mask in /x notation, would it be correct to take the subnet id/X
or the broadcast ip/x?

I.e. for a 256 IP subnet: 10.10.0.0/24 or 10.10.0.255/24?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

`10.10.0.0/24` would be a subnet.

You often see that the last bytes are left out: `10.10.0/24` or `10.10/16`. This notation seems not to be official; however, even the ICANN and the IETF use the notation.

A notation like `10.10.0.123/24` is often used to specify the address of a host and the subnet the host belongs to at once.

You might use the notation `10.10.0.255/24` to specify a broadcast address and the subnet at once.

---

By the way: Even the authors of the RFCs seem to be confused about the notation:

Many RFCs (such as RFC 1878) claim that the notation "`10.10.0.0/24`" is specified in RFC 1519. However, RFC 1519 seems not to specify what character(s) is (are) used to separate the address from the prefix length, so "`10.10.0.0 :-) 24`" would be a valid notation according to RFC 1519. RFC 4632 seems to be the first RFC explicitly specifying that the slash character ("`/`") shall be used together with IPv4 subnets.

Comment: Lol, il start using :) to separte them then!

Comment: There's a notation (obsolete?) where missing octets are filled in the middle, so 10.11 stands for 10.0.0.11 and 10.11.12 stands for 10.11.0.12. That way, *10.10/16* is somewhat ambiguous - referring to either the subnet 10.10.0.0/16 or the IP address 10.0.0.10/16 - and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 2):

It's convention to use the network address, aka. the first address in the IP block, then referring to the network. So in you example, the network address would be 10.10.0.0/24. However, CIDR notation would also allow you to write just the IP for a host in question, as 10.10.0.147/24 for example, as the network 10.10.0.0/24 is still implied.